# Capturing BZIP2 Termination within Perl

Tags: perl, bzip2

Here is what I have so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use IO::Compress::Bzip2 qw(bzip2 $Bzip2Error);
use File::Find;
use File::Basename;

my $directory = "/usr/www/op1/public/server";
my @list_of_files;

find sub {
        return if -d;
        my $current = basename("$File::Find::name");

        if ($current =~ /\.bz2$/i)
        {
                #print "<$current> is already compressed! Moving along!\n";
                return;
        }

        print "<$current> is being compressed!\n";
        bzip2 $File::Find::name => "$File::Find::name.bz2";

        if (!("$Bzip2Error" eq ""))
        {
                print "\n$Bzip2Error at $File::Find::name\n";
                print "Trying again to compress <$current>\n";
                bzip2 $File::Find::name => "$File::Find::name.bz2" or print "FAILURE 2!!!";
        }
}, "$directory";
```

Basically, while bzipping if it decides to terminate:

```
<bobsagot> is being compressed!
<arthur.bsp.bz2> is already compressed! Moving along!
<reed.bsp.bz2> is already compressed! Moving along!
<bobby.bsp.bz2> is already compressed! Moving along!
<bigjoe.bsp> is being compressed!
Terminated
```

It will immediately pickup from where it failed and keep going, however I don't get an error printed out from `$Bzip2Error` so I'm at a loss. How can I capture the event of bzip2 failing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you make a cut-n-paste error in your code? The line that starts with "**system(**" is out of place.

Is the script terminating on its own during the **bzip2** call?

If you write the the code like this what happens?

```
if ( ! bzip2 $File::Find::name => "$File::Find::name.bz2")
{
    print "\nBzip Errir is [$Bzip2Error] System Error is [$!] at $File::Find::name\n";
}
```

Comment: The snippit you posted doesn't print anything :(

Comment: How is the script terminating? bzip2 should return false if the compression fails.

Comment: I think my execution time is limited to 60 seconds so this is outta my reach.

Comment: Are you running in a setup where the script gets killed after 60 seconds? If so, it depends how it is being killed.

Comment: You could try  END { print "\nBzip Error is [$Bzip2Error] System Error is [$!] \n" }

Comment: Yeah this is a lost hope I was just messing with a minor web server on shared hosting. I've moved everything to my VPS so yeah...

Answer (score 0):

Shared hosting limit perl execution time to 60 seconds. Lost hope :D